# Storing Table from join as PHP varible

Tags: php, mysql

So I have got as far as this many to many join

```
$manyJoin = "SELECT projects.name AS project_name ,tags.name AS tag_name 
             FROM `projects` AS projects                                 
             LEFT JOIN `project_tags` AS pt 
             ON projects.id = pt.project_id 
             LEFT JOIN `tags` AS tags ON pt.tag_id = tags.id
             WHERE tags.name IS NOT NULL;";
```

**Which gives me this table**

```
project_name    tag_name
project_1       iphone
project_1       android
project_2       android
project_2       windows
```

How do i then query this table to `echo` each project with a list that projects tags. Or can i rewrite my query to get what i need? Thanks.

**Wanted output.**

```
project_1 iphone android
project_2 android windows
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in php:

- Add an `ORDER BY projects.name` to the query
- Keep track of the current project name when you get your rows. When the project name changes add a new row and display the name and then fetch rows to display the tags until the project name changes again.